# Optimizing byte array reading and writing in C#

Tags: c#, .net, performance, winforms

I have a code snippet that reads data from a `Process` output stream and writes it to a `MemoryStream`. I'm looking for suggestions on how to optimize the performance of this code, specifically in terms of reading and writing the byte array.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/ffmpeg.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-i \"{"C:/Users/google/Desktop/New folder/video.mp4"}\" -vf \"select=gte(n\\,{master_frame})\" -vframes 1 -q:v 2 -f image2pipe -c:v bmp -";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.Start();

    using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

        pictureBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
        {
            pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(outputStream);
        }));
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there are any optimizations I can make to improve the performance of this code. I have considered increasing the buffer size, but I'm unsure about the optimal value to use. Additionally, I'm wondering if there are any asynchronous alternatives that could improve the reading and writing operations.

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The code is optimized.  Making the buffer larger than 1024 will make code run quicker.

Comment: OP starts a subprocess for every single frame, successively (`master_frame` increments), and this subprocess has to decode the video upto that frame, anew, every single time. this became apparent from [other questions by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76577060/slow-frame-rate-and-high-resource-usage-when-extracting-frames-with-ffmpeg-in-c) where the calling behavior was shown.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of ["Slow frame rate and high resource usage when extracting frames with ffmpeg in C#"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76577060/slow-frame-rate-and-high-resource-usage-when-extracting-frames-with-ffmpeg-in-c), posted by yourself the same day.

Your code performs poorly because creating a new ffmpeg instance takes a lot of time, thus resulting in a big lag before stream reading actually starts. See [my answer on your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76608691/9399492).

Increasing the buffer size will indeed improve performance (as @jdweng suggested) but it won't be significant at all compared to the delay caused by the ffmpeg process creation.

Comment: please flag questions as duplicates if you think they are duplicates. this is possible starting from 50 reputation.

Comment: I actually got my 50 rep this morning. Can't see anything to flag as duplicate though. I can flag for "Spam", "Rude or abusive", "Plagiarized content" or "Need a moderator's attention", nothing about duplicates. Not sure this would count as "Plagiarized content" since it's a duplicate of a post made by the exact same person.

Comment: yes, at this point, this question was labeled as a duplicate already, by some power user who can do it without flagging/voting.

Comment: Ah yes, right, I didn't notice. Still thanks for making me aware of this possibility.